# Mongo ordering a $near with another secondary sort

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geolocation, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a list of shops they have a useCount and a geolocation.
How would I search and order by useCount but also have a property on each object returned signifying how close they are to me.

schema:

```
{
    name: String,
    useCount: { type: Number, index: true },
    location: { 'type': {type: String, enum: "Point", default: "Point"}, coordinates: { type: [Number],   default: [0,0]} }
}
```

e.g results

```
shop1 usecount-12 closest-3 geo-1333.222,222.222
shop2 usecount-3  closest-1 geo-1333.222,222.222
shop3 usecount-1  closest-2 geo-1333.222,222.222
```

Comment: This looks very SQL like in the data and not very MongoDB like. What does your data actually look like and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Presuming your data is actually properly arranged for MongoDB and looks something like this:

```js
{
    "shop": 1,
    "usecount": 12,
    "closest": 3,
    "geo": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [1333.222,222.222]
    }
}
```

And your coordinates are in fact in "longitude/latitude" order as is requireed from GeoJSON and MongoDB and that you have a geospatial index that is ["2dsphere"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/), then your best option for "composite sort" is using the [**`$geoNear`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) aggregate command pipeline, along with aggregation [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/):

```js
Model.aggregate(
    [
        { "$geoNear": {
            "near": {
               "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [1333.222,222.222]
            },
            "distanceField": "dist",
            "spherical": true
        }},
        { "$sort": { "dist": 1, "usecount": -1 } }
    ],
    function(err,results) {

    }
)
```

Where the `$geoNear` projects the "distance" as the nominated field here in "dist", and then you use that in the `$sort` along with the other field "usecount" as shown here in descending order for the "largest" value if "usecount" first, and within each "dist" already sorted.

The aggregation framework though `.aggregate()` does more than just "aggregate" documents. It is your "main tool" for projecting new values into a document, useful for such things as sorting results by values that "calculate" by one means or the other.

Unlike [`$near`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/)  ( or [`$nearSphere`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/) ) the distance is returned as a true field in the document rather than just a "default" sort order. This allows that key to be used in the sorted results, along with any other field value present or projected into the document at the `$sort` stage.

Also noting that your data here does not appear to be valid spherical coordinates, which is going to cause problems with GeoJSON storage and also a "2dsphere" index. If not real global coordinates but coordinates on a "plane, then just use a plane legacy array for "geo" as `[1333.222,222.222]` and a "2d" index only. As well the argument to "near" within `$geoNear` is simply an array as well, and the "spherical" option would then not be required.

But possibly a problem with typing in your question as well.